# Is “être après” + verb a regionalism?

Tags: expressions, traduction, régionalismes

A translation style guide I read through issues the following recommendation (paraphrased):

> Il ne faut pas employer « être après faire » au lieu de « venir de faire ».
>
> <strike>*Il est après manger.*</strike> *Il vient de manger.*

There are a few recommendations in this guide that make me wonder: are they addressing absurd calques from other languages the translators on their rosters speak, or are these discouraged alternatives actually *courant* in the *langue populaire* ?

If I listen as I walk down the streets of a Francophone city, will I hear « Elle est après + verbe » ?

<sub>(This is not a question about *venir de faire*, which I know is correct.)</sub>

Comment: This is probably an advice for a given language (but I don't know which one) and "il est après manger" does not make sense in French from France. You will never hear "elle est après " + verb in France. However, "elle est après " + somebody exists with different meanings like "she is really (romantically) interested in" + somebody or "elle est toujours après lui" (she is always on his back) which is much less positive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est plutôt qu'il [ne faudrait pas](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=845) employer *être après* pour parler de l'action en cours dans le sens *d'être en train de* suivi de l'infinitif ; la *BDL* considère cet emploi comme une [*impropriété*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=2816), soit « une erreur de vocabulaire qui porte sur le sens du mot ». Reste que j'ai souvent entendu ce « tour » bien populaire au Québec (voire [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/30899)), où le sens ne peut jamais en être que l'action est complétée depuis peu comme avec *venir de faire* (je ne connais pas ce sens de *être après* qu'évoque le *style guide*). Par ailleurs on pourrait l'écrire dans des dialogues, par exemple, d'où l'utilité de le (re)connaître...

> Le gouvernement **est en train de** modifier la loi électorale. (et
>   non : Le gouvernement *est après* modifier la loi électorale) (*BDL*,
>   OQLF)

On mentionne aussi cet emploi au *Glossaire du parler français au Canada* (début 20<sup>e</sup>) : « Être après faire quelque chose = être en train de faire qqc., travailler à qqc. ». Ce glossaire réfère à l'emploi de *après à* chez [Molière](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Fourberies_de_Scapin) (« Je suis après à m’équiper [...] », *Les Fourberies de Scapin*), Bossuet et Regnard et celui de *après de* chez Malherbe et Chapelain ; il note que ces locutions semblent hors d'usage malgré la présence de *être après à* au lexique dans Ac.7 ; on le trouve dans [Ac.8](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/apr%C3%A8s) et [Ac.9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/apr%C3%A8s) (avec mention *très vieilli*). Il réfère aussi aux dialectes d'Anjou, de Touraine et Orléanais etc. ; voir aussi au [FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/14477) (p. 179, col. gauche).  *Le bon usage* (14<sup>e</sup>, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 2007) signale que selon [*Le Bidois*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zn1YAAAAYAAJ&dq=Syntaxe%20du%20fran%C3%A7ais%20moderne%20bidois&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22%C3%AAtre%20apr%C3%A8s%22) le tour s'emploierait encore dans la langue familière. Le LBU14 ajoute qu'il s'emploie sans le *à* dans le Berry, en Franche-Comté, en région franco-provençale et en Auvergne ; dans un cas on l'a classé comme « très familier ». Historiquement, [Vaugelas](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6565932p/f289.item) n'aimait pas ; [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/apr%C3%A8s) (fin 19<sup>e</sup>) non plus (« Quelquefois on entend dire : Il est après s'habiller. C'est une faute. Il faut : Il est après à s'habiller. »).

Comment: Bizarre, le guide se trompe même du sens de la tournure interdite ! Influencé peut-être par le régionalisme maritime "I'm after eating ~ Je viens de manger" en anglais ... En tout cas, il est utile de savoir que certaines des expressions douteuses ont bien le statut qu'on leur attribue ici.

Comment: Pour une réponse plus complète, accepterais-tu d'ajouter une ou deux exemples où, à l'orale, l'expression ne serait pas trop gênante ?

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard it but *être après* + verb is [documented](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_apr%C3%A8s) to be a regionalism (Canada / Louisiana / Poitou-Charentes-Vendée).